# How create less bins in histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

How can I please set less bins in this histogram in gnuplot?

Here are http://leteckaposta.cz/514785176 data for this histogram.

Thank you

```
clear
reset
f(x)=a*exp((-(x-b)**2)/(2*c**2))
a=27.3634;
b=131.12;
c=11.0518;
set key off
set border 3
set yzeroaxis
set boxwidth 0.3 absolute
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder

bin_width = 0.1;

bin_number(x) = floor(x/bin_width)

rounded(x) = bin_width * ( bin_number(x) + 0.5 )
set ytics nomirror font "Times New Roman,12"
set xtics nomirror font "Times New Roman,12"
set key top right font "Times New Roman,12"
set xlabel "Počet detekcí" font "Times New Roman,12"
set ylabel "Četnost" font "Times New Roman,12"
plot [95:175] 'poisson.txt' using (rounded($1)):(1) smooth frequency with boxes title "Naměřeno", f(x) title "Gaussova křivka"
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Add the appropriate language tag

Comment: I am sorry, I use gnuplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Philipp K Janert's book "Gnuplot In Action" (p. 256f) and [this](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/smooth.html) web sample, I came up with the solution for you as below (comments in the source file):

```
f(x)=a*exp((-(x-b)**2)/(2*c**2))
a=27.3634;
b=131.12;
c=11.0518;

stats 'poisson.txt' nooutput        # produces statistics about the datafile
N = STATS_records                   # number of records in the file

set key off
set border 3
set yzeroaxis
set boxwidth 0.8 absolute           # set the width of your boxes
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder

bin_width = 2                       # controls the number of boxes / bins
bin(x, s) = s*int(x/s)              # normalising

set ytics nomirror font "Times New Roman,12"
set xtics nomirror font "Times New Roman,12"
set key top right font "Times New Roman,12"
set xlabel "Počet detekcí" font "Times New Roman,12"
set ylabel "Četnost" font "Times New Roman,12"
plot 'poisson.txt' u (bin($1,bin_width)):((N/2)/N) smooth freq title "Naměřeno" w boxes, f(x) title "Gaussova křivka"
                                   # ((N/2)/N) controls the height of your boxes
```

which yields

[image]